# Can I declare a constructor that accepts Name-Value arguments to define immutable properties?

Tags: matlab, constructor, immutability, argument-validation

Since MATLAB R2019b it has been possible to [declare name-value arguments from class properties](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/validate-name-value-arguments.html#mw_de9b2056-9dc2-421c-9c7e-d2c4400a95be) which has created an elegant way to define a class that can be constructed with a declaration of its properties without repeating each defined property in the code for the constructor:

```
classdef C < handle & matlab.mixin.SetGet
    properties
       Prop
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = C(props)
            arguments
                props.?C
            end
            set(obj,props)
        end
    end
end
```

Which than can then be instantiated thus:

```
>> C(Prop = 1)

ans =

  C with properties:
  
    Prop: 1
```

If instead I need the properties to be immutable, it becomes less clear how to neatly do this. Simply changing `properties` to `properties (SetAccess = immutable)` is no good, because the `.?` syntax only seems to support public settable properties, so attempts to instantiate then result in the error:

```
Error using C
Invalid argument list. Function 'C constructor' does not accept input arguments because class 'C' referenced in the arguments block does not have public settable properties.
```

In this case, one could explicitly declare `props.Prop` as a name-value constructor argument instead, and assign each property one-by-one to the object, but this code coupling becomes more bloated and unmaintainable as the class properties become more numerous.

Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 1):

For classes with no other repeating arguments to the constructor, the Name-Value argument pattern can be replicated by defining repeating arguments and the values assigned using dynamic subscripting:

```
classdef C < handle
    properties (SetAccess = immutable)
       Prop
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = C(name,value)
            arguments (Repeating)
                name (1,1) string
                value
            end

            for ii = 1:numel(name)
                obj.(name{ii}) = value{ii};
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Unlike the `.?` syntax with public-settable properties that assigns arguments to a `struct`, this can't be combined with other repeating arguments to the constructor, so doesn't allow for as flexible a function signature but will fill what seems otherwise to be a gap in many cases.